# Laravel - Barryvdh DomPDF - loadHTML not working fine

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-blade

This is my code. What I am trying to do is load multiple PDFS, for that I am using loadHTML to get the raw html from the views and then concatenate the variables ($somaPDFS). The problem is that it's only loading the first concatenated variable, in this case it's only loading the $html_analisoRisco_pdf.
This is my code. Could anyone help?

```
$html_pecas_pdf = view('pecas.pdf', compact('peca','cronograma','aprovador','data_aprovacao','linhas','fases'))->render();
    $html_analiseRisco_pdf = view('analise_risco.pdf', compact('peca', 'analise'))->render();
    $somaPDFS = $html_analiseRisco_pdf . $html_pecas_pdf;

    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($somaPDFS)
    ->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');        
    dd($somaPDFS);
    $pdf->output();

    return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: Im guessing each view has its own HTML tags and it stops or errors out when it encounters the closing tag.

Comment: Yes they do. Any idea to solve that?

Comment: Besides manually removing the duplicate tags...